# Calling a tabular table function to apply calculation on each row

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to calculate the number of working days between two given dates across each row of a table. I am hitting the toscalar limitations when I try to perform this as a scalar function and so am trying to do this in a tabular function so that I can ultimately join it to my master table.

My issue now is the that I think the calculation is only being performed on one row of the table and that result is being propagated to all other rows.

The scalar function I tried was:

```
let tb = datatable(IncidentName:string, CreatedTime:datetime, ClosedTime:datetime) [
'008af5f7-67b4-43bf-b97c-f33a9928fa99',datetime('2023-07-04T13:12:24.1966667Z'),datetime('2023-07-04T13:18:32.2625594Z'),
'db03cdad-8a89-4e54-aaae-ae3c73702fc5',datetime('2023-07-03T07:19:33.22Z'), datetime('2023-07-06T10:20:07.343693Z')];
let workingTime = (IncidentName:string, CreatedTime:datetime, ClosedTime:datetime)
{ 
//declare public holidays
let holidays = datatable(Holidays: datetime)
    [
    datetime(2022-04-15),datetime(2023-04-07),datetime(2023-05-01),datetime(2023-12-25)];
let middle_days = range Date from datetime_add('day', 1, startofday(CreatedTime)) to datetime_add('day', -1, startofday(ClosedTime)) step 1d;
let middle_work_days = toscalar(middle_days
    | where dayofweek(Date) / 1d between (1..5)
    | where Date !in (holidays)
    | summarize count());
middle_work_days
    };
tb |
extend workingdays = workingTime(IncidentName, CreatedTime, ClosedTime)
```

This results in the error:
"Relop semantic error: CRT0018: 'toscalar': can't use 'CreatedTime' as it is defined outside its row-context scope. (see: https://aka.ms/toscalar_limitations)."
The tabular function I'm trying is:

```
let tb = datatable(IncidentName:string, CreatedTime:datetime, ClosedTime:datetime) [
'008af5f7-67b4-43bf-b97c-f33a9928fa99',datetime('2023-07-04T13:12:24.1966667Z'),datetime('2023-07-04T13:18:32.2625594Z'),
'db03cdad-8a89-4e54-aaae-ae3c73702fc5',datetime('2023-07-03T07:19:33.22Z'), datetime('2023-07-06T10:20:07.343693Z')];
let workingTime = (wt:(IncidentName:string, CreatedTime:datetime, ClosedTime:datetime))
{ 
//declare public holidays
let holidays = datatable(Holidays: datetime)
    [
    datetime(2022-04-15),datetime(2023-04-07),datetime(2023-05-01),datetime(2023-12-25)];
let sT = toscalar(wt | project CreatedTime);
let eT = toscalar(wt | project ClosedTime);
let middle_days = range Date from datetime_add('day', 1, startofday(sT)) to datetime_add('day', -1, startofday(eT)) step 1d;
let middle_work_days = toscalar(middle_days
    | where dayofweek(Date) / 1d between (1..5)
    | where Date !in (holidays)
    | summarize count());
wt 
| extend middle_work_days
    };
workingTime(tb)
```

The tabular results in:

| IncidentName | CreatedTime | ClosedTime | middle_work_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 008af5f7-67b4-43bf-b97c-f33a9928fa99 | 04/07/2023, 13:12:24.196 | 04/07/2023, 13:18:32.262 | 0 |
| db03cdad-8a89-4e54-aaae-ae3c73702fc5 | 03/07/2023, 07:19:33.220 | 06/07/2023, 10:20:07.343 | 0 |

How can achieve this either using a scalar function so I can extend the result to my master table, or using the tabular so that I can join the tables?